# Google Search Console - Newly added site showing up in the Google webmaster but not showing in Search console

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-search-api, google-search-console

I have created my google service account and using it to make API calls. I am submitting site via API call at search console, call successfully completed with status 204 but site is not coming up in google search console UI.

Request URL is here
https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/siteUrl

Here is my code

```
$client = new Google_Client();                
$client->setAuthConfig('google-meta-search.json'); //Using service account credentials
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters');
$request = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
$resultsGoogle = $request->sites->add('https://whatyouplay.com');

//List the added sites  - check out the attached screenshot
$list = $googlerequest->sites->listsites();
```

OUTPUT:

[image]